# In the testing of cython code, is it valid to use ctypes?

Tags: c++, c, testing, cython, ctypes

Suppose I am given some (thoroughly tested) C or C++ code. And suppose I have implemented some functionality in Cython that makes use of this C/C++ code. The Cython functionality basically serves as a Python interface to my C/C++ code.

Now I wish to write Python code to test my Cython code. Is it valid to use ctypes to access the C/C++ compiled shared object and compare that with the results from the corresponding Cython functionality?

I tend to think the answer to this question is yes, this is a valid test. My hesitation is that, without knowing the internals of Cython, it seems possible or likely that Cython is doing under the hood exactly what I'm proposing to do in this test.

Here is some sample code. The C header file some_c_code.h is:

```
/* a is 1-dimensional array of size 5 */
void times_2(double* a);
```

And the C implementation file some_c_code.c is:

```
void times_2(double* a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        a[i] *= 2;
}
```

The Cython file is:

```
# distutils: sources = some_c_code.c

cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "some_c_code.h":
    cdef void times_2(double*)

def py_times_2(a: np.ndarray):
    cdef double[:] b = a
    times_2(&b[0])
```

We compile the Cython code into the file abc.cython-37m-linux.so. Separately, we also compile the C code into another file libtestabc.so.

Now I propose to test the function `py_times_2` with the following Python code:

```
import abc
from ctypes import cdll, c_double, POINTER
import numpy as np

def main():
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libtestabc.so')
    dll_times_2 = dll.times_2
    dll_times_2.argtypes = POINTER(c_double)
    dll_times_2.restype = None

    a, a_dll = np.arange(5), np.arange(5)
    a_ctype = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(a_dll)

    abc.py_times_2(a)
    dll_times_2(a_ctype)

    assert np.allclose(a, a_dll)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is this a valid test of the Python function `py_times_2`?

Comment: I would say it is a valid test. However, the amount of boiler plate code would drive me crazy to the point, that I wouldn’t write any tests at all in the long run.

Comment: I can't really imagine this catching many bugs. It's fine, but I doubt if it's worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Any suggestions for tests that require less effort or are more helpful in catching bugs?

Comment: @waynemystir Generally the bugs you have to worry about in Cython wrappers are memory-management errors (i.e. not ensuring object lifetimes) and these usually show up in more complex programs (unfortunately). One solution that might not be too much work is to reproduce some of the C/C++ "whole program" tests in Cython. You have a good known answer to compare to...